# $abx^2+bcy^2+acz^2=(xyz)^2+2abc$ has no integral solutions if $a,b,c,x,y,z >1$?

Tags: diophantine-equations

let $a,b,c,x,y,z$ be all pairwise coprime integers
. Show that: $$abx^2+bcy^2+acz^2=(xyz)^2+2abc$$ has no integral solutions if $a,b,c,x,y,z >1$. I tried to confirm the results in wolfram but I am totally clueless as to how to prove this. Any hints?

Comment: I think you posted this recently; I don't know what you mean by nontrivial; mostly, i don't know where you got the problem. Note: $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3xyz$ has infinitely many solutions in positive integers. The related $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = Axyz + B$ will have infinitely many solutions if any. Your term $(xyz)^2$ is so large that you cannot have two out of three variables large and one small, so Markov's setup does not apply. For any triple $(a,b,c)$ I imagine the set of solutions is finite. But again, where did you get this?

Comment: I edited the question for clarification. I vaguely remember seeing this problem in an Algebra book from Singapore regarding symmetric Diophantine equations. I checked out on wolfram the possible solutions and noted indeed there are no solutions. I am puzzled as to why it is so. I was expecting infinitely many solutions. But you pointed out something very interesting regarding the size of $(xyz)^2$.Perhaps, that's the reason. I'll look at the problem from this angle.

Comment: @Ramunjndscpl: I changed a phrase since you could not have confirmed your conjecture as it is incorrect. See W. Jagy's counter-example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is wrong

```
  a   b   c      x   y  z
 49  39  25     41  11  4  


Sun Dec 20 13:08:27 PST 2015
```

Comment: I guess Wolfram needs an upgrade. it's misleading. Thanks Will Jagy.

Comment: @Ramunjndscpl actually you need to get an ordinary procedural language and learn how to use it. People seem to like Python, and then there is Sage. I use C++. You should not be posting false statements and getting people to waste time on them as thought they were true.

Comment: @WillJagy, it is not a false statement. Please note in the stem, it's stated as a question. The reason why I thought there were no actual solutions it's because I was mislead by Wolfram.

Comment: @Ramunjndscpl: This type of multi-variable Diophantine equation is beyond Walpha. It can answer, for example, "solve x^2-5y^2=1 over the integers". But not "solve a^2+b^2+c^2 = d^2 over the integers". In fairness to Walpha, solving _arbitrary_ multiple-variable Diophantine equations is an intrinsically hard problem, and it is not something one can expect to find free over the Internet.

Comment: @WillJagy: Individ found a nice parameterization that, for carefully chosen parameter, yield prime $a,b,c,x,y,z$. A quick search already yielded 220 solutions, such as, $$293,\, 17389,\, 61,\, 11,\, 2,\, 7\\37493,\, 2286589,\, 61,\, 11,\, 2,\, 193$$  and so on. I wouldn't be suprised if the system turned out to have an infinite number of pairwise co-prime solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for example $(a,b,c,x,y,z) = (1,1,7,1,5,3)$ is a solution to this equation.

So, what do you mean by "non-trivial"?

Comment: Computer search suggests that there are no solutions with all numbers different from $1,0,-1$. I suspect this is what was meant.

Comment: @user133281, I edited the question for clarification. I am however pleasantly surprised at your  answer. I wonder why Wolfram did not provide such answer.

Comment: @Wojowu   $(49,  39,  25,     41,  11,  4)$

Comment: @WillJagy It seems that I was just close of finding a solution - I went with $a<20,b<40,c<60$.

Comment: @Wojowu I started by allowing $\gcd(c,x) > 1$ and found some worthwhile sextuples for this revised problem with somewhat smaller entries. It seemed worth it to raise the bounds, although I was not really expecting a solution to the problem with all gcd's required to be $1.$ It's a habit from decades of this, I weaken restrictions to get a little output from the computer. Frustrating, and uninformative, seeing nothing at all.

Answer (score 2):

$$abx^2+bcy^2+acz^2=(xyz)^2+2bca$$

$$x=2n+1$$

$$c=2n^2+2n+1$$

$$a=(2n^2+2n+1)y^2+z^2$$

$$b=4n^2(n+1)^2y^2+(2n^2+2n+1)z^2$$

Comment: @invidid, you always have the weirdest parametric solutions. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @individ: He wants it [_pairwise coprime_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers). That means, if you have a set of $n$ integers $x_1, x_2, x_3,\dots x_n$, then _all_ possible pairs $x_i, x_k$ must not share any factor.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII How can there be problems?  You just have to choose the numbers are what we need.  For example.  $n=2$ ; $x=5$ ; $y=2$ ; $z=7$ ; $c=13$ ; $a=101$ ; $b=1213$ .

Comment: @individ: That's very good, all $a,b,c,x,y,z$ are primes, hence are automatically pairwise co-prime. You should edit your answer to include that example, and maybe a few others also.